# RxJava Observable Zip Causes Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android, leakcanary

I am using RxJava's Observable.zip method to combine two API calls into one result. For some reason I am getting a memory leak despite the fact that I unsubscribe from the subscription. I am not sure if this a bug on my end or if there is something I need to do with the creation of the Observable.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
...

subscription = Observable.zip(
      api.getConfiguration(),
      api.getSettings().map(r -> r.getData()),
      new Func2<ConfigurationResponse, List<Datum>, Struct>() {
        @Override
        public Struct call(ConfigurationResponse config, List<Datum> data) {
          return new Struct(data, config.getCopy(), config.getSettings());
        }
      }
    )
      .compose(Schedulers.applyApiSchedulers())
      .subscribe(
        struct -> {
          configurationManager.set(struct.data, struct.copy, struct.settings);
          startNextActivity();
        },
        error -> {
          startNextActivity();
        }
      );
}

protected void onDestroy() {
  if (!subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Here is the trace from Leak Canary.

[image: leak trace]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the sources, api.getConfiguration(),
      api.getSettings()?

Comment: `api` is just a Retrofit interface so there is not really.

Comment: what version of retrofit?

Comment: I am using Retrofit - 1.9.0, RxJava 1.0.14 and RxAndroid 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the leak comes from the `subscription` itself as you seem to keep referencing the `Subscriber` through it. Try clearing that reference in `onDestroy` and check again for leaks.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a leak in retrofit, a similar one seems to have been reported [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/945).

Note that if retrofit leaks the subscriber, you may be able to limit the impact if your mapper func no longer references your activity instance.
In your case `Struct` is probably a non-static instance class (hence having an implicit reference to the activity instance), if you manage to make it static w/o referencing the activity, you'll likely get rid of this very leak.